# Differernce between alphabets in C?

Tags: java, c

I wanted to know how to you find the difference between alphabets,for ex: difference between a and d is 3, between s and u is 2. I would like to know the methods in both c and java.

Comment: Simply subtract the characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 'd' - 'a';
```

will have `i` set to 3 which is the difference